# Unable to access hard disk due to hibernation or sleep in windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows, hibernate

I am getting unable to access to harddisk error in ubuntu. As I understand, it is because windows hibernated itself when I was trying to close it. And there are lots of solutions for that issue. However these solution reqires to boot in windows and now I can't boot windows and prevent to hibernate it self. When I try to boot it from ubuntu boot screen, an odd screen appears which is in ubuntu theme but a little bit corrupted.

Comment: Well, what you have to do is boot into Windows, and go: `Control Panel > System and Security > Power Options > Change what the power buttons do > Change settings that are currently unavailable > Turn off "Fast Startup"`

Comment: I couldn't boot into windows. That was the problem. Anyway I manage to boot it with safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to boot into Wİndows with safemode. Enter windows in boot screen and press f8. I dont know why it didn't came up to my mind.